# Python: how to import func from the nested subdir

Tags: python, path, python-import, importerror

I have a project with the following structure

```
app
├── app
│   └─- __init__.py
│   └── file.py
└── notebooks
    └── notebook.ipynb
```

I try to import func inside `notebook.ipynb`

I use `from app.file import func_name` but it returns me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Then I added path into `sys` with
`sys.path.append('/app')` and it returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.file'
```

How did I do wrong?

Comment: you could do ```sys.path.append('pathto/app')``` and then ```from file import function_name```

Comment: @Nin17 but is it possible to do it automatically after unpacking repo?